# Need to add a excerpt to a category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want to add a excerpt into the edit category of wordpress instead of Description

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooEtM.png

Does anyone know if this is possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend with various type of fields the categories (and also other type of WordPress objects) using a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

In particularly for an excerpt you would use a "Text Area" or a "Wysiwyg Editor" between the [available field types](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/).

Comment: @ashleygibson I’m happy to have been of help! Please check this answer as "accepted" ;)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone struggling with my issue you need to download the plugin ACF and make a wysiwyg then send that to either your category or taxonomy

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Vpn.png

then echo out that field in your loop